# Remove dash(-) from uuid generated by funciton __UUID in jmeter

Tags: javascript, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am new to jmeter and I am calling the `$(__UUID)` function in jmeter to get the uuid. The uuid is generated like this

```
14c5f969-ba57-4493-b4ba-01f1c8b6908d
```

How do I remove the dashes from the final result to get uuid as

```
14c5f969-a574493b4ba01f1c8b6908d
```

I am calling the `$(__UUID)` function like this "HTTP request defaults" samples in jmeter with PATH textfield set to

```
/end/fa7dbe2de11f4f08b3c941ff8b5b4c08/now/${__UUID}/
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm correctly getting your question and you want to remove all dashes from the path it can be done via [Beanshell Pre Processor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PreProcessor).

Add it as a child of HTTP Request(s) where replacement is required and put something like

```
String path = sampler.getPath();
sampler.setPath(path.replaceAll("-",""));
```

to "Script" area.

This code will replace all occurrences of dash symbols in HTTP Request path.

See [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for more information regarding Beanshell scripting in Apache JMeter and kind of Beanshell cookbook.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I am getting an error while using this. Error is  "Error invoking bsh method" . Do I need to import anything before using it.

Comment: Can you provide the screenshot of your test plan? The above answer should work!

Comment: No imports are required, if you use Beanshell PreProcessor added as a child of HTTP Request it should work as is.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not answer for your question but as alternative you can use:

```
${__javaScript(new Date().getTime())}
```

it will provide timestamp for you, in most cases it is good enough...

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently using this script in the BeanShell PreProcessor and it works perfectly.

```
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Header;

sampler.getHeaderManager().removeHeaderNamed("my-uuid");
String uuid = java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString().replace("-","");

sampler.getHeaderManager().add(new Header("my-uuid", uuid));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `beanshell pre-processor` and add the lines below

```
String jMUUID = "${__UUID}";
vars.put("UUID",jMUUID.replace("-",""));
```

OR

```
vars.put("UUID","${__UUID}".replace("-",""));
```

Else you can directly use below in your URL path

```
${__BeanShell("${__UUID}".replace("-"\,""),)}
```